# Setting up a response Enum that takes in a nil for a Struct whenever that option doesn't apply

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following Enum which takes 2 `structs` when there is an `error`. However, depending on the `error` sometimes a `LogError` will not apply or sometimes a `UserError` will not apply. For instance, for user input validation errors I do not want to write anything to the log but I do want to display the error to the user and so I would like to send a nil for LogError in those cases. How can I go about doing that?

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(Int, LogError, UserError) //error code, error title, error message
}

struct LogError {

    var errorMessage: String
}

struct UserError {

    var errorTitle: String
    var errorMessage: String
}
```

I would like to return the response using the enum as shown below

```
return completion(.Error(9999, nil, UserError(errorTitle: kINVALID_FIELDS_ERROR_TITLE, errorMessage: errorMessage)))
```

However, I am getting the error

**nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'LogError'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `LogError` optional if you want to be able to use `nil` instead:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(Int, LogError?, UserError)
    //                      ^
}
```

Comment: It is Swift convention to name enumeration cases starting with a lowercase letter. Btw UserError should also be optional **"or sometimes a UserError will not apply"**